# Finding the derivative of $f(x)=\int_1^{\infty}\frac{e^{-xy}}{y^2}dy,\:\:\:x\in(0,\infty)$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, analysis, derivatives, lebesgue-integral

> Let 
>   $$f(x)=\int_1^{\infty}\frac{e^{-xy}}{y^2}dy,\:\:\:x\in(0,\infty)$$
>   Show that $f(x)$ is differentiable on $(0,\infty)$, find the formula for $f'(x)$? Is $f(x)$ twice differentiable?

I'm thinking to define a sequence as follow
$$f_n(x)=\int_1^n\frac{e^{-xy}}{y^2}dy.$$

To show $f_n(x)$ is differentiable, I'm thinking to show the following limit exists,

$$\lim_{h\to 0}\int_1^n\frac{e^{-(x+h)y}-e^{-xy}}{y^2h}.$$

To be able to pass the limit inside the integral, we can apply the Lebesgue dominated convergence theorem. So I want to see if  I can apply it. Since $\frac{e^{-(x+h)y}-e^{-xy}}{y^2h}$ is bounded by $\frac{e^{-uy}}{y}$, (where $x\leq u\leq x+h$) which is integrable on $[1,\infty).$

Hence $f'_n(x)=\int_1^n\frac{d}{dx}(\frac{e^{-xy}}{y^2})dy=\int_1^n-\frac{e^{-xy}}{y}dy. $

Now, $\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_1^n\frac{-e^{-xy}}{y}dy=\int_{1}^{\infty}\frac{-e^{-xy}}{y}dy.$

However I see a problem here, since in fact, we have 
$$f'(x)=\lim_{h\to 0}\lim_{n\to{\infty}}\int_1^n\frac{e^{-(x+h)y}-e^{-xy}}{y^2h}.$$

But I'm not sure, if I'm allowed to interchange these two limits. I appreciate any hint or alternative proof.

Comment: I would try taking two derivatives (passing the limit through both times) first. The result can be computed precisely in that case. Then try anti differentiating.

Comment: @Joel why would you do that? I wanted kinda think about the sequence of the derivatives, but $(0,\infty)$ is not compact and bounded, also, do I need to show the sequence of derivatives ( the first or second) is uniformly convergent to their limits?

Comment: I think the problem of interchanging the limits is removed if you forget about taking a limit with $n$ and re-do your argument using $\int_1^{\infty}$.  I think LDC still applies since the exponential function has a finite integral over $[1, \infty)$. But you would need to bound the absolute value $|e^{-(x+h)y}-e^{-xy}|/|y^2h|$ by a pure function of $y$ (so get rid of the $u$ variable, you can keep the constant $x$ variable though).  Joel's approach temporarily assumes the interchange, gets a "candidate" non-integral expression for $f''$, then integrates back.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's take two derivatives under the integral first, and we will talk about justifying it after the fact.

Consider $$f(x) = \int_1^\infty \frac{e^{-xy}}{y^2} dy.$$

Then two derivatives with respect to $x$ are easy to take here:

$$f^{\prime\prime}(x) = \int_1^\infty e^{-xy} dy = -\left.\frac{e^{-xy}}{x} \right|_{1}^\infty = \frac{e^{-x}}{x}.$$

---

Note that the denominator gets completely cancelled by the chain rule. Hence, (provided we can justify the derivatives) we have $$f^{\prime}(x) = \int \frac{e^{-x}}{x} dx = e^{-x}\ln(x) + \int_1^x \ln(\tau)e^{-\tau}d\tau + C$$ for some $C \in \mathbb{R}$.

Finally, we can see that as $x \to \infty$ that $f'(x) \to 0$. We conclude that $f'(x) = e^{-x}\ln(x) + \int_1^x \ln(\tau)e^{-\tau}d\tau$.

---

To justify passing the derivative through the integral, we can appeal to the measure theory version of the [Leibniz integral rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule#General_form:_Differentiation_under_the_integral_sign).

What we need is a function that bounds $g(x,y) = \frac{d}{dx} \frac{e^{-xy}}{y^2} = -\frac{e^{-xy}}{y}$ independent of $x$ that is also integrable. For any $\delta > 0$, we have $$|g(x,y)| \le \frac{e^{-\delta y}}{y}$$ for all $x \in [\delta, \infty)$. Therefore, given $x > \delta$, we have $$\frac{d}{dx} \int_1^\infty \frac{e^{-xy}}{y^2} dy = \int_1^\infty \frac{d}{dx}\left( \frac{e^{-xy}}{y^2} \right) dy.$$ Since, $\delta$ was chosen to be an arbitrary positive number, we may conclude that this formula holds for all $x > 0$. A similar argument can be performed for the second derivative as well.

Comment: Ah, right. Thanks for catching that @Mattos

Comment: @Joel The person who taught us Analysis, never talked about Lebesgue dominated convergence theorem. he expected something related to uniformly convergent, that's why I came up with the sequence $f_n(x)$. Is there any way to do it only by definition?

Comment: @Joel I also have a question regarding  Leibniz integral rule. I'm kinda concerned about the upper limit which is $\infty.$ So it seems, I can always apply this rule, even if the upper bound is $\infty$

Comment: You are right @Michael. I corrected the error.

Comment: @Parisina, the bound on the interval isn't important for Lebesgue dominated convergence. The decay of the integrand is what matters in this case.

Comment: @Joel My other question: In the last step, where you pass the derivative through the integral, why does the lower limit of integration become zero?

Comment: @hungryformath that occurred precisely because of nothing. I guess I habitually think of the lower bound as zero and it slipped in here. Thanks for catching my mistake.

Answer (score 3):

By Fubini's theorem,$$
f(x) = \int_1^{+\infty} \frac{\mathrm{e}^{-xy}}{y^2} \,\mathrm{d} y = \int_1^{+\infty} \int_x^{+\infty} \frac{\mathrm{e}^{-uy}}{y} \,\mathrm{d} u\,\mathrm{d} y = \int_x^{+\infty} \int_1^{+\infty} \frac{\mathrm{e}^{-uy}}{y} \,\mathrm{d} y\,\mathrm{d} u,
$$
thus$$
f'(x) = -\int_1^{+\infty} \frac{\mathrm{e}^{-xy}}{y} \,\mathrm{d} y.
$$

Comment: Nicely done. @AlexFranko